# How to access resource files in Java code running on Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I've tried setting a class loader in the init() function like so:

```
classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

I subsequently try the following in my OnScheduled method:

```
InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

My Java project has a file at src/main/resources/foo/bar. Regardless of whether I pass "foo/bar" or "/foo/bar" as "fileName" in the above code, classLoader.getResourceAsStream() returns null. I have verified that the file is inside the NAR archive, at META_INF/bundled_dependencies/foo/bar.

What's the best way of accessing the file's contents from my code?

Comment: Put resource file inside jar bundled into nar.

Comment: Yes what Dagget said, the "foo/bar" directory should be part of your processor's JAR, not directly in the NAR.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyProcessor.class.getResourceAsStream(...);
```

Is the way to go here. You want to use the classloader associated with your customer processor or controller service, not the current running thread.